# what database design should be a good approach for a user activity module

Tags: mysql

i am working on a project in which i need to make a module based on user activity, but since my project assuming to be having a large number of members in future ahead , i am confused about how to make the database for the user activity . i have 2 ideas in mind , taking a example of facebook . suppose i have 5 tables

and all of them have timestamp which is updated accordingly with the user activity being  performed , 
then should i make a simple query and arrange a users activity according to the timestamp from all the 5 tables , **OR**

i make a new table named

activity

and store each activity of a user separate , but i think when the users increase with time it would a huge database of user activity table , where i can easily get the activity performed by that user by timestamp in the above 5 tables . i am really confused , can anyone help me with the right choice ?

Comment: What are all the activities you expect an user to perform?, What is your project?. Throw more light on your projects objective when you are asking around to make a design decision.

Comment: my project is on social networking , and the main activities i expect a user to perform are of , messages, comments, pic upload to gallery, likes,ratings to videos . i am not able to decide on what way out of the 2 i mentioned above would be the best for a database with large number of members

Comment: Its so obvious that you should do it with 5 tables and from reading your question, your tone was inclined to that too. Lets do it with 5 tables. I also think there are many other things that can be done to increase the performance of your app which again would depend solely on your requirement.

Comment: can u share your views on what more could be done as , those 5 tables already exist and with help of timestamp common in each of them we can filter at what time user performed what action , instead on creating a new table to store all the activity by all the users . i couldn't think of any more solutions then these two , if you have any more solution can you please share it

Comment: Lets not have extended conversations in comments. Please visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11242/chat